# A period "." in the <body> tag of homepage Magento

Tags: html, magento, period

There's a "." in the code of the body tag on one of the storeviews. Any knowledge on getting rid of it would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried applying white-out to your screen? We can't, since your screen is too far away...

Answer (score 0):

There was a dot "." inside the area of 'Miscellaneous scripts' in the backend of Magento. I searched through all storeviews a few times tho, must have overlooked it.